# Bootstrap layout footer colliding with other elements

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass

[image]

Okay, so I'm building a layout in bootstrap + Rails.

If I upload a larger picture the footer does not clash with the text box with the content information but with the picture I am using there are issues.

what can I do to use the elements(pictures) I like and ensure that the footer never collides with the textbox?

the view looks like this

```
`<h1>Contact#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/contact/index.html.erb</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content-overlap">
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <p> For investment information call: <br>
        +phonenumberhere237 or +phonenumberhere8 <br> <br>
          For legal contact:+phonenumberhere0 <br>
           For partnership: phonenumberhere7142 <br>
                  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-overlap">
    <img src="assets\administration.jpg"  >
  </div>
</div>`
```

Using bootstrap and rails 5.1.4 (but it turns out the code comes from a codepen not bootstrap so ignore that forked code is here https://codepen.io/Anthematics/pen/RMwZJG)

The footer itself renders as a partial in my layouts folder - this issue persists in a few places but this has the least elements and once solved here I am sure I can solve elsewhere.

in HTML my footer looks like this `<p class = "footie"> Victoria University 2018 </p>`

in css

```
.footie {
  &:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
  }
}

.footie {
  background: black;
  color: wheat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using clearfix where needed ? https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/

Or your could try :

```
footer {
  &:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Taking your code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-overlap">...</div>
  <div class="image-overlap">...</div>
</div>
<div style='display: block; clear: both;'></div>
```

Comment: we had a guy who was heading up the front end on this unexpectedly leave so I've been cleaning up after him but I'm an intern and much newer to programming! if I just write the clearfix in the footer then that would do it?

Comment: no problems don't worry. You should try it yep; understand that `clear: both` (it speaks by itself) is the useful thing in there

Comment: so I can just add that (the css) in the footie class? 
 
` <p class = "footie"> hi SO </p>`

or try putting the footie class in a div class called clearfix ?

Comment: try the last example; otherwise, go though the bootstrap linked page. Either way, you'll work this out without much problems. If you don't try you won't be able to verify what I've answered (: !